# How do I write contents of a variable to a text file in Rebol 2?

Tags: rebol, rebol2

Newbie question here... 
I'd like to write the output of the "what" function to a text file.

So here is what I have done:

I've created a variable called "text" and assigned the output of "what" to it

text: [what]

Now I want to write the content of the "text" variable to a txt file...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way to write the output of statements to a file is to use

```
echo %file.log
what
```

with `echo none` you end this

```
>> help echo
USAGE:
      ECHO target 

DESCRIPTION:
     Copies console output to a file.
     ECHO is a function value.

ARGUMENTS:
     target -- (Type: file none logic)

(SPECIAL ATTRIBUTES)
     catch
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is not really a value returned from the `what` function:

Try the following in the console:

```
 print ["Value of `what` is: " what]
```

So `write %filename.txt [what]` will not work.

Instead, what you could do is to look at the source of `what`

```
source what
```

which returns:

```
what: func [
    "Prints a list of globally-defined functions."
    /local vals args here total
][
    total: copy []
    vals: second system/words
    foreach word first system/words [
        if any-function? first vals [
            args: first first vals
            if here: find args /local [args: copy/part args here]
            append total reduce [word mold args]
        ]
        vals: next vals
    ]
    foreach [word args] sort/skip total 2 [print [word args]]
    exit
]
```

See that this function only prints (it doesn't return the values it finds)  We can modify the script to do what you want:

```
new-what: func [
    "Returns a list of globally-defined functions."
    /local vals args here total collected
][
    collected: copy []
    total: copy []
    vals: second system/words
    foreach word first system/words [
        if any-function? first vals [
            args: first first vals
            if here: find args /local [args: copy/part args here]
            append total reduce [word mold args]
        ]
        vals: next vals
    ]
    foreach [word args] sort/skip total 2 [append collected reduce [word tab args newline]]
    write %filename.txt collected
    exit
]
```

This function is a little hackish (filename is set, but it will return what you want).  You can extend the function to accept a filename or do whatever you want.   The `tab` and `newline` are there to make the file output prettier.

Important things to notice from this:

1. Print returns unset
2. Use `source` to find out what functions do
3. `write %filename value` will write out a value to a file all at once.  If you `open` a file, you can write more times.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly elementary: use `write` if you just want to save some text, `read` to recover it; use `save` if you want to store some data and use `load` to recover it.

```
>> write %file.txt "Some Text"
>> read %file.txt
== "Some Text"

>> text: [what]
>> save/all %file.r text
>> load %file.r
== [what]
```

You can get more information on each word at the prompt: `help save` or view online: [`load`](http://help.rebol.info/load), [`save`](http://help.rebol.info/save),  [`read`](http://help.rebol.info/read) and [`write`](http://help.rebol.info/write).